# What are the security risks of passing an authentication token in react using props?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-props, react-component

I am building a react application using class-based components and want to pass an authentication token in the props. Could an external person connected to my browser get the token and start doing things with it?

I apologise if this seems a very basic question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything stored in a client-side application is viewable and modifiable by:

- end-users
- attackers conducting a XSS attack

In the case of an authentication token, the risk of modification is mitigated by the use of a message signature; if the message contents are changed, the signature wouldn't match the message for the signer's public key and the token is therefore rejected.

However, visibility of the token is still a problem to consider - it could lead to replay attacks on your application's endpoints, giving end-users the capability to execute actions that you might not want them to. If your application is vulnerable to XSS, then an attacker could also execute those actions.

In general, a good practice is to treat anything provided from the client as malicious unless explicitly proven otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a problem, what you should focus on is not having sensitive information inside the token because it can be "grabbed" and "seen" by "anyone" (some attacks might be able to get the token and thats ok as long as it's well protected, that means for example, that the token expires and does not have sensitive information)

Comment: What sort of sensitive information might be in the token? I imagine session start and end times might be in a token and that would tie a user to a particular location for that time? Also what if someone used my token while I was mid-session to 'piggy-back' on my session?

Comment: That is possible but only if they have access to your token (ex: you are suffering an attack) what you should not have is user password (user id is usually fine) basically any information that you don't want to be public should not be present in the token.

Comment: Ok we're in the context of a web app for satellite communication - it is very conceivable someone would try every possible way to gain access to someone else's user session - what are your thoughts?

Comment: To be honest that's up to the user to use the application safely and not use external scripts, please take a look at Dominic answer about possible attacks (XSS) etc. My point still stands, token should not contain sensitive information, you should assume that a token is "public" (everyone might see it see stuff about attacks etc).

Comment: also you should maybe explore other options regarding auth excluding JWT (when used correctly it's ok) but there might be other "safer" options

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it as encrypted format then i think there should not be any harm in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the token with props it is a mistake. If you use libraries such as Axios you need to add to the main Axios file some authorization headers which contain the token. This is one of the very few scenarios of token usage in React, Vue etc... So i don't think you should send it with props because you don't need to do that. Also you will need to save that token inside Local Storage or Cookies when you receive it, therefore you can access it from any file you want and extract all the data you need from it without bothering about passing it via props.

Comment: IF you use axios, and if you dont? sure you can create a wrapper for the fetch function, what if i don't even want to do that? What if I'm just trying to extract some information from the token?